# Не работает carousel

Tags: jquery

Делаю сайт в `cms netcat`.
Прописываю скрипты (двойные кавычки экранированы для неткат).

```
<script src=\"/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js\"></script>
<script src=\"/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js\"></script>

        <!-- Jquery carousel -->

        <script type=\"text/javascript\">

        function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
        {
            // Disable autoscrolling if the user clicks the prev or next button.
            carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
                carousel.startAuto(0);
            });

            carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
                carousel.startAuto(0);
            });

            // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
            carousel.clip.hover(function() {
                carousel.stopAuto();
            }, function() {
                carousel.startAuto();
            });
        };

        function brandcarousel_initCallback(carousel)
        {
            // Disable autoscrolling if the user clicks the prev or next button.
            carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
                carousel.startAuto(0);
            });

            carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
                carousel.startAuto(0);
            });

            // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
            carousel.clip.hover(function() {
                carousel.stopAuto();
            }, function() {
                carousel.startAuto();
            });
        };

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
                auto: 4,
                wrap: \"circular\",
                scroll: 1,
                size: 4,
                animation: 2000,
                initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
            });

            jQuery('#brandcarousel').jcarousel({
                auto: 2,
                wrap: \"circular\",
                scroll: 1,
                visible: 4,
                animation: 2500,
                buttonNextHTML: null,
                buttonPrevHTML: null,
                initCallback: brandcarousel_initCallback
            });
        });

        </script>
```

прописываю в html-коде

```
<div class=\"picture\">
<div class=\"picture_self\">
                    <ul id=\"brandcarousel\">
                        <li><img src=\"/images/s_pic.jpg\" /></li>
                        <li><img src=\"/images/s_pic.jpg\" /></li>
                        <li><img src=\"/images/s_pic.jpg\" /></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class=\"picture_mask\"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

(картинка пока одна и та же, просто для примера)
carousel не работает. 
Что-то не дописано или не так написано, в чем причина?

Comment: а Firebug что говорит ?

Comment: у меня он не установлен, я им не пользовалась никогда. без Firebug как-то можно выяснить, в чем дело?

Comment: jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({

где элемент с id = mycarousel?

Comment: У меня элемент с id=brandcarousel, в html-коде <ul id=\"brandcarousel\">, mycarousel это для другого места

Comment: ну тогда зачем вам jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({... ?

Comment: mycarousel это для другого места в коде, я уже ответила выше

Comment: NetКот убогая CMS в понимании программиста (для допилов и перепилов).  
Даже лицензию отбирают, если править ядро(!!!)  
Там сам чёрт ногу сломит.  
(2 года работал с ней, перешёл на Drupal)
Смените CMS и сами удивитесь, как всё подключаемое - быстро и просто начинает работать!

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте после

```
initCallback: brandcarousel_initCallback,
```

эту строку:

```
itemFallbackDimension: 300
```

Comment: ну я создал такой же html файл с такой же разметкой и у меня с 
itemFallbackDimension: 300 все работает...

ставьте firebug и смотрите ошибку... иначе не решим проблему

Comment: вкл firebug -> перейти на вкладку console в firebug -> кликнуть enabled -> перегрузить страницу.

Comment: ага, и лучше вообще убедится что netcat скрипты подключил.

Comment: всё поправила, ошибок нет, но карусель все равно не работает

Comment: вот здесь выложен код http://jsfiddle.net/JHJPS/, посмотрите, пожалуйста, не могу понять, что не так.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6EmsT/

Comment: ну не работает у меня((((
не знаю, что не так http://n.inetech.ru/

Comment: очень странно... на http://n.inetech.ru/ почему-то не срабатывает

jQuery('...').jcarousel({

так как беру копирую исходный код страницы, создаю свой index.html вставляю туда скопированный код и... работает